# WinApi Клики и скриншоты свернутого окна

Tags: windows, winapi, screenshots

Как сделать скриншот свернутого окна, и можно ли в это окно посылать клики мышки по координатам?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что в свернутом окне что-то есть? Система туда `WM_PAINT` не посылает, так что в нем скорее всего просто мусор. Окна вообще отрисовываются только в той части, которая видна на экране.

Comment: А не свернутого окна, которое просто перекрыто другими окнами тоже не получится?

Comment: Тоже не получится, поскольку обновляется только неперекрытая область. Да и вообще - вы же хотите снимок **экрана**. Что вы прочитаете в невидимой области? Окно ведь свой контекст не хранит, а только получает на время рисования. Невидимого изображения просто не существует.

Comment: А отправлять клики по координатам в видимое не активное окно, без перемещения курсора возможно?

Comment: Почему невозможно? Получайте хэндл окна и шлите ему любые сообщения, `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` или еще что.

Comment: Cooller Floyd, насчет кликов в неактивное окно: смотря каким методом сделано окно, если кнопки, поля этого окна сделаны, на основе классов типа Button, Edit, то можно "кликать" и оконными сообщениям типа - WM_LBUTTONDOWN , а если интерфейс окна по сути является "нарисованным" - то только через имитацию курсора мыши - sendiput, но в этом случае, окно должно быть активное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Краткий ответ: ***скриншот свернутого окна сделать невозможно***.

Здесь сразу можно предъявить возражение: если это так, то что мы видим, когда наводим курсор на иконку свернутого окна в панели задач? Система показывает уменьшенное изображение окна, стало быть откуда-то она его берет, верно?

Поэтому полным ответом будет: ***скриншот свернутого окна сделать можно, но с оговорками***.

Чтобы было понятно как это сделать, вспомним, как происходит рисование окна. Когда окно или его часть становится видимым, система посылает окну сообщение `WM_PAINT`. Обработчик сообщения `WM_PAINT` должен получить контекст рисования (DC) вызовом `BeginPaint` и вывести туда все, что в окне есть. Точнее, в его клиентской части. Система сама обрежет все ненужное (сделает так называемый clipping) и выведет на экран только ту часть, которая видна.

Здесь сразу нужно подчеркнуть важный момент - содержимое окна система не хранит. После отрисовки и освобождения контекста все данные выбрасываются. Если системе понадобится обновить окно или отрисовать какую-то часть, ставшую видимой, она просто снова пошлет сообщение `WM_PAINT`. Поэтому посторонняя программа может получить только то, что в данный момент отображено на экране, скрытой части изображения просто не существует.

Как же система получает уменьшенное изображение окна в панели задач? Очень просто - она шлет ему то же самое `WM_PAINT`, а для рисования передает ему специальный контекст для уменьшенного изображения. Программа вообще не различает, отрисовывает ли она свое окно нормально на экране, или в виде иконки.

Теоретически другая программа может подменить `BeginPaint` и делать то же самое, но практически задача эта очень непростая, да и далеко на всякая программа может получить такой доступ. В целом вариант малореальный.

Есть еще один вариант: как раз для этой цели в WinAPI существуют сообщения `WM_PRINT` и `WM_PRINTCLIENT`. Они работают как `WM_PAINT`, но прямо в сообщении содержат ссылку на контекст, куда программа должна рисовать. Поэтому `BeginPaint` подменять не нужно, достаточно просто послать окну одно из этих сообщений, указав свой контекст. Вот только программа совершенно не обязана обрабатывать эти сообщения. Сложно предположить какой процент программ поддерживает рисование через эти сообщения, ясно только что далеко не все.